# Spring controller - inject property into AbstracController

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController extends AbstractController {
}


public abstract class AbstractController {
   private int connectionTimout;
}
```

In my `servelet.xml` I am injecting the property but I would like this property to be set directly in AbstractController and not in each sub controller.

```
<bean id="testController" class="com.test.controller.testController">
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${rest.connectionTimeout}" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is bean definition inheritance. You can declare an abstract bean (will never be instanciated) to hold some property definitions, and use it as a parent in concrete beans declarations. That allows you to follow the DRY principle even if multiple beans share same properties. Here you can do:

```xml
<bean id="abstractController" abstract = "true"
        class="com.test.controller.AbstractController">
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${rest.connectionTimeout}" />
</bean>

<bean id="testController" class="com.test.controller.testController"
        parent="abstractController">
   <!-- other properties but not connection timeout already inherited from parent -->
</bean>
```

(ref: Bean definition inheritance in Spring framework reference manual)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Value("#{rest.connectionTimeout}")
private int connectionTimeout;
```

Autowiring make the field available, even if it is final. Try:

```
@Value("#{rest.connectionTimeout}")
private final Integer connectionTimeout = null;
```